# SQL SELECT AVG on entire table (all rows) but output only rows which fulfill a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to basically perform the following query shown below, but also wants to a WHERE clause to only select the min,max,mean city population value of a country if the country fulfills the condition of having atleast one city which have a population larger than 100 000. If the country does not have any cities larger than this value it should not be shown in the output. However, a WHERE clause would affect the calculated min,max,mean. How could this be performed?

Query:

```
SELECT 
country.name as country_name, 
MIN(city.population) as min_pop, 
MAX(city.population) as max_pop, 
ROUND(AVG(city.population),2) as mean_pop
FROM city

LEFT JOIN country
ON country.country_id = city.country_id

GROUP BY country_name
;
```

Comment: Use HAVING clause for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: Specifically `having count(*) filter (where population > 100000)`

Comment: `HAVING MAX(city.population) > 100000` would do it actually... means at least one city has that much population.

Comment: Yes, that's true. A count test could short-circuit though so conceivably it's still useful.

Comment: The "having count(*) filter..." query returns: "ERROR:  argument of HAVING must be type boolean, not type bigint". The "HAVING MAX...." query works though! Thank you so much!

Comment: Make it an answer for me to mark it as the accepted answer.